# Meteor - Exception from Sub. Publish Function returned an array of non-Cursors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Im trying to publish a collection, but my console says that it return an array.

**server/publish.js**

```
HeartCount = new Mongo.Collection('heartcount');

Meteor.publish("currentHeartCount", function() {
    return HeartCount.find().fetch();
});
```

**RelypheTopContainer.jsx**

```
class RelypheTopContainer extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

  currentHeartCount() {
    return HeartCount.find().fetch();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {}
  data() {
    const params = this.props.params;
    const id = params.id;

    this.state = {
      subscriptions: {
        relyphe: RelypheSubs.subscribe('oneRelyphe', id),
        heartCount: Meteor.subscribe('currentHeartCount', id)
      }
    };
}
```

**RelypheTop.jsx**

```
<div className='dates' onClick={handleClickDate}>
     <div className="particle-box" />
     <div id="output">0</div>
     <span style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{ 
         birthDate&&relypheDate?`${birthDate} - ${relypheDate}`:
         birthDate?birthDate:
         relypheDate?relypheDate:
         ''}</span>
</div>
```

Im trying to put the current count into the #output div to be displayed on all users screens.

Answer (score 1):

`.fetch()` converts a cursor to an array. Use:

```
Meteor.publish("currentHeartCount", function() {
    return HeartCount.find();
});
```

Comment: It is saying that the function is an unexpected token. https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9qrmuoiw8oktbl/Screenshot%202016-08-11%2016.10.19.png?dl=0

Comment: Do I put it into the RelypheTopContainer class?

Comment: It is not giving me any errors but it is only displaying the hearts on the client side of the app and not the server side.

Comment: Well, you can't really _display_ on the server so what's the issue on the server? _Publish_ is done by the server, _Subscribe_ is done on the client.

Comment: Where should I put the Meteor.subscribe statement specifically in which file or line?

Comment: Right where you have it in `RelypheTopContainer.jsx` should be fine.

Comment: It saying that the Meteor.subscribe is still an Unexpected token, check out the first link I posted in the first comment to see what i am talking about.

Comment: Make sure that `RelypheTopContainer.jsx` is under `/client` as well as any other client-side code you have.

Comment: Everything is already under the client. Even the publish.js in  server directory. Also what do you mean by putting the Meteor.subscribe in RelypheTopContainer.jsx like where the heartCount subscription is?

Comment: ps. the unexpected token error doesn't refer to the `Meteor.subscribe` function, it refers to some piece of punctuation/a delimiter. Check your file to make sure you don't have a stray comma, semicolon, bracket, or quote somewhere.